# How to get angular variable to javascript when using scope() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

This is how I get my input. sql table -> php slim -> angularjs -> website.

I need to GET a variable in javascript that php slim is returning to angular.

Right now I'm using this in $( document ).ready(function() {.

```
var $element = $('div[ng-show="game"]');
var scope = angular.element($element).scope();
console.log(scope);
```

It returns this in console.
[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Is it just a `scope.game.total_rating`?

Comment: And why are you using jQuery's `ready` with Angular? You seem to have a misconception of how to structure applications with AngularJS.

Comment: @runTarm - no, it returns error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_rating' of undefined".

Comment: @plaxl - yes I know now, but I learnt that too late into the project. New to angularjs.

Comment: What is the output of `scope.$id`?

Comment: @runTarm it gives plain "003"

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular controller just create your JQuery method there.

```
//Controller
function someController($scope) {

    $scope.game = GetFromSlim();

    $scope.yourMethod = function(){
       $('#someDiv').innerHtml($scope.game.total_rating);
    }
}
```

Then you can just call your method from the view using angular.

```
//View
<div ng-controller="someController" ng-app>
   <div id="someDiv"></div>
   <button ng-click="yourMethod()">Just do it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The action needs to happen when the page loads. Or to be more precise, when the values from slim are loaded.

Comment: Why not load values from slim in the Angular controller? You're doing it on document ready right? Can you show me a snippet of your Slim call

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I was able to fix it with a workaround, or rather the way it should have been fixed in the beginning: <div data-icon="j" ng-class="{'perma_rate perma_rate2': game.user_rating >= '5'}" class="icon rate_star_small"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 or AngularJS 2 ++

Without scope method also can be passed as below. You have to write somecodes inside angular page(Declare, define and redefine) and some in javascript.

**A. In angular (i used in common angular page) write below code**

//Declare and Define of variables

```
environmentStringify = {
'project_url':'172.23.77.82:4200/myangularproject/', 
'testMode':true
};
declare var environmentStringify: any;
environmentStringify = JSON.stringify(environment);
```

**B. in html page (i used index.html inside head and script tags) write below codes**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var environmentStringify = "{{environmentStringify}}";
    var environment = null;

    function isJsonString(str) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(str);
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function setJSEnvironmentVariable(){
        if(isJsonString(environmentStringify)){
            environment = JSON.parse(environmentStringify);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function(){
                setJSEnvironmentVariable();
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    setJSEnvironmentVariable();
  </script>
```